# count the occurrence of words in pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of some keywords,let's say.

```
searchterms = 
['Java language',
 'C Language',
 'C++',
 'Python Language',
 'JavaScript',
 'Pascal Language',
 'Statistics',
 'Visual Basic',
 'Objective-C',
 'MATLAB']
```

I have a pandas dataframe, which consists of texts and the author, text corpus for each author i.e. a single text entry is quite long, let's call it `df`.

Now, I want to create a rule. My main objective is to classy the users into three groups, i.e. whether the user is beginner/intermediate/advanced.
My idea is like to search for the counts of these search terms and create separate column for each terms and represent the counts.
if any of the search term variable created has  the following condition, I can label it to beginner/intermediate/advanced.

```
any_serch_term < 10 - beginner
any_serch_term > 10 and < 50  - intermediate
any_serch_term > 50  - advanced
```

Sample of df

```
user      text
a     is home to one of the largest collections of ...
b     Commercial Floor Plans       Sully Statio...
c    I had no idea the issues a code of conduct It’...
d    My week on Twitter  1 Retweet 824K Retweet Re...
e     Tory MPs who guzzle £3000000 in taxpayer fund...
```

the output df like, representing the counts.

```
user      text      Java languageC      Language      C++      Python Language ........
```

Thanks.

Comment: I was trying regex and also look for aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

```
for terms in search_terms:
    df[str(terms)] = map(lambda x: x.count(str(terms)), df['text'])
```